# Why does Jest fail on a test suite in my Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, yarnpkg, ts-jest

I have an Expo React Native project, and am having some issues running my pipelines in Gitlab.

I have a `gitlab-ci.yml` file outlining the stages of my pipelines. If I follow the steps in this file and run everything manually on my machine, there are no problems. However, in Gitlab, there are a couple of things failing.

1. When running `yarn` in one of my directories, I get an `ENOENT: no such file or directory` error relating to one of my node modules `@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios`, even though I have this dependency in my `package.json` (and yes this is in the correct directory).
2. When my pipeline runs the command `jest --ci`, right at the end it says it fails on one test suite, and says that 44/45 test suites passed and 1 failed. Which I do not understand because, when run locally, I only have 44 test suites. Then what makes even less sense to me is, this test suite that fails, looks something like:

```
FAIL .yarn/v6/.tmp/e733dde53c498c2e8e93bc6d79dee518/test/test.js
  ● node-websql test suite › encountered a declaration exception
    TypeError: this.timeout is not a function
       9 |
      10 | describe('node-websql test suite', function () {
    > 11 |   this.timeout(300000);
         |        ^
      12 |
      13 |   before(function () {
      14 |     if (typeof process !== 'undefined' && !process.browser) {
      at Suite.<anonymous> (.yarn/v6/.tmp/e733dde53c498c2e8e93bc6d79dee518/test/test.js:11:8)
      at Object.<anonymous> (.yarn/v6/.tmp/e733dde53c498c2e8e93bc6d79dee518/test/test.js:10:1)
```

I have 0 idea what this test suite is, as all the others are as I expect, something like `src/atoms/<NAME>.test.js`, which I myself created.